# I want to set an alarm 3 times in a day in android

Tags: android

I want to set an alarm 3 times on a daily basis and that alarm should send 3 different different notification.n for that I have tried  this [tutorial](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=alarmreceiver-excellent-tutorial). This tutorial help me for setting 1 alarm whenever I set second alarm application sends notification for second alarm only.

and now I am sharing my code. I tried this code and it is running finely for 1 alarm.

MainActivity

public class AlarmManagerMainActivity extends Activity {

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_manager_main);

//  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

      /*calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
      calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);

      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,4);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
      calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);*/
    /*Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
    Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_now.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,4);//set the alarm time
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,20);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    if(cal_alarm.before(cal_now)){//if its in the past increment
        cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }

      Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmManagerMainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmManagerMainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    */

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmManagerMainActivity.this , MyReceiver.class);     
       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmManagerMainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,15);
       calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alarm_manager_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Service:

public class MyAlarmService extends Service{
     private NotificationManager mManager;

```
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       super.onCreate();
    }

   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "IN Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),AlarmManagerMainActivity.class);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

       mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

}

Receiver:

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "IN REceiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
       context.startService(service1);  
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Are you just trying to send the same 3 notification 3 times per day, 8 hours apart?

Comment: And I want to send 3 different notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have completed this exercise.

AlarmService

---

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
                {
              // code here what ever is required
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                 hr = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute= cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            sec= cal.get(Calendar.SECOND); 
             if(hr==10 && minute==00){
           flagInt=1;
           sendNotification(1);
        }else if(hr==20 && minute==00){
           flagInt=2;
           sendNotification(2);   
        }else if(hr==22 && minute==00){
           flagInt=3;
           sendNotification(3);
        }else if(hr==23 && minute==00){
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ACTIVITY_PREF_NAME, 0);
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(IS_ACTIVITY_CHANGE, false); 
        editor.commit(); // commit changes  
    } 
           handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
                }
            };
   handler.postDelayed(r,60000);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you are providing all your notifications with the same id (0), therefore they will all replace the previous one

```
mManager.notify(0, notification);
```

You need a way of differentiating the notifications and giving them a different ID.

Comment: glad to help. If this answer has solved the problem for you then please select it to mark as solved.